# Deactivate code in python without changing indentation or adding comments

Tags: python

I suspect the answer to this question will be a big NO!
But here goes.

Is there a way to deactivate (temporarily) long code snippets without having to comment every line or putting an if FALSE: and indenting every line?

As an example, say I have the code

```
for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
    DoSuff(A)
    ###DO Mode stuff
    ###....
    Done(A)
```

However, since I'm still developing the code I don't want this lengthy loop to run. My options are as far as I'm aware:

Comment away

```
#for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
    #DoSuff(A)
    ####DO Mode stuff
    ####....
    #Done(A)
```

or wrap in a `false` if-statement

```
if False:
    for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
        DoSuff(A)
        ###DO Mode stuff
        ###....
        Done(A)
```

both of which require me to manipulate every line I want to deactivate.

Is there some more clever way of doing this without having to change the indentation or adding comments at every line. (Except maybe putting `LargeNumber=0` here.)

Comment: If it always applies to the same functions being skipped, you might add a `@decorator` to those functions...

Comment: Don't think there's a better way. At the same time, I think commenting a block of lines is clearer and less prone to be forgotten than to add some sorts of "skip"-labels into the code. What is the problem with commenting many lines anyway? Your editor surely has a mass-comment feature.

Comment: You can comment a chunk of code with `""""` and `""""`

Comment: If you are using IDLE then you can highlight everything you want to comment and press alt 3 and use alt 4 to uncomment

Comment: @HarryPotfleur Neat idea... unless that code itself contains some multi-line string, of course...

Comment: @tobias_k : Yes, Emacs can do this, it just found it ha hassle. I like the if(false) dresser since it clearly show to me that this code should be activates at some later time.

Comment: @HarryPotfleur: Could you write a short answer with an example. I don't seem to be able to reproduce what you are suggesting.

Comment: In case of that for loop, you could also just insert a `break` at the very top: `for ... in ...: break`

Comment: No need to put `if False` on a new level, just put it on that line and comment the rest: `if False: #for A in range...`

Comment: What's wrong with indenting a whole block? In most editors, this can be done at once.

Comment: @tobias_k please stop calling my editor [Shirley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlpxl0WzaXg&feature=youtu.be&t=34)

Comment: @georg: Sneaky but usefull trick. Sometimes however, it might not be a loop that needs to go, it could be a sequence of statements, like when i'm doing a lot if plotting, and what to disable that for a wile.

Comment: @MikaelFremling: actually, if you have such large chunks of code (that presumably even don't feet on a single screen), it's about time to consider a better structure. How about moving your plotting code in a function which you can easily comment and uncomment?

Comment: @georg: Let me be clear that this problem that i'm having would most often happen somewhere in the development phase of the code, while working more or less interactively with it. You know, trying some things and then discarding them. You don't necessarily want to start making functions for everything that is a long snippet of code at this stage. But I agree with you in in principle.

Comment: @MikaelFremling I answered with an example

Comment: I have to question why modifying every line to be omitted is considered an issue. It is not surely the correct thing to do? Is this perhaps not something of an XY problem, with the correct 'solution' being the functionality of a given editor to easily add & remove the comments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested, what I proposed :

to comment a large code :

```
"""
for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
        DoSuff(A)
        DO Mode stuff
        ....
        Done(A)
"""
```

Everything in between the 2 `"""` will be commented. However as tobias_k said, it doesn't work well if you have multi-line strings in your code.

But, as he also said, you can make it work like this :

```
"""
print 'anything with sinple quotes instead of double quotes'
"""
```

Comment: But assuming that you do not wildly mix `'''` and `"""` multi-line-strings, you can just use the quotes that are not used in the code block.

Comment: I don't understand - this works fine for me with three quotes `"""` but with four quotes `""""` I get an error "*EOL while scanning string literal*" am I missing something here?

Comment: yeah my bad, it's 3 not 4 :)

Comment: that explains a lot ;)

Comment: I also added @tobias_k solution

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but it will not work if the block of code already contains """. Hence another drawback to using Python - no easy way to disable a section of code w/o making a lot of changes.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- if you have a particular long-running function you want to skip during development, you could define and use a decorator to skip that function and add it to its declaration (of course, this will only work if the function does not return anything that would be used later on)

  ```
  def skip(f):
      def _f(*args, **kwargs):
          print("skipped function", f.__name__)
      return _f

  @skip
  def long_running_function(foo):
      print("executed function")
  ```
- in case you want to skip a loop, as in your example, just add a `break` statement at the top

  ```
  for i in range(10):
      break # TODO speed up development; remove for production!
      long_running_function(i)
  ```

Personally, however, I would just go with mass-commenting the block of code you want to skip.

Comment: Python 2 (but not 3) has leakage. The break will leave `i=0` whereas letting it run leaves `i=9` and commenting will not set `i` at all, can potentially cause confusion if script is a bit scrappy.

Comment: @uhoh Good point, but IMHO using a loop variable after/outside of the loop is somewhat smelly, anyway. Variables not being set the way they would be is a problem with all these approaches.

Comment: "scrappy" = "smelly" it can happen by accident, but I agree that one shouldn't do it on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here are several ways which you can use:

- Move the code into a function/method. You can now deactivate it by changing a single line.
- Move the code to a new function in a new module. Create a second module which contains the same function but empty. Switch between the two modules in `import`
- Create a config flag and protect the code with an `if`. That way, you have a single place in your config to enable/disable the code.
- Move all your code into a class. Split the code that you want to deactivate into a method. Extend the class and overload the method with an empty one. When you use the class, use the base or extended class.
- If you don't have multi-line strings in the code, you can use

  ```
  for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
      deactivated = '''
      DoSuff(A)
      ###DO Mode stuff
      ###....
      Done(A)
      '''
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
   break
   DoSuff(A)
   ###DO Mode stuff
   ###....
   Done(A)
```

I've generally found that using a 'pass', 'return', 'continue', or 'break' works nicely for testing...

Comment: Python 2 (but not 3) has leakage. The break will leave `i=1` whereas letting it run leaves `i=LargeNumber` and commenting will not set i at all, can potentially cause confusion if script is a bit scrappy.

Comment: True, but most python programmers don't use the values of loop-defined variables outside of the loop, and the question asks for a quick way to deactivate code for testing; presumably the author would be aware of this.

Comment: it can happen by accident - then the `break` introduces even more variability. There are a lot of python users who are not exactly "Python programmers." You are right, it is not a good idea to do intentionally!

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like feature flags. [Feature Flags](https://flask-featureflags.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a (looks like maybe defunct?) library that provides the sort of functionality that you're looking for.

You could also create a feature flag context manager that looks something like this:

```
class SkipWith(Exception): pass

@contextmanager
def feature_flag(flag):

    @contextmanager
    def check_active():
        deactivated = ['four', 'five']
        activated = ['one', 'two', 'three']
        if flag in deactivated:
            if flag == 'five':
                print('Five is right out')
            raise SkipWith()
        else:
            yield
    try:
        yield check_active
    except SkipWith:
        print('Skipping flag')


with feature_flag('one') as check, check():
    print('one')

with feature_flag('two') as check, check():
    print('two')

with feature_flag('five') as check, check():
    print('five')

# Ouput:
# one
# two
# Five is right out
# Skipping flag
```

Answer (score 1):

An improvement to @CoMartel's docstring method is to make it switchable with a single character change:

```
#"""
for A in range(1,LargeNumber):
    DoSuff(A)
    ###DO Mode stuff
    ###....
    Done(A)
#"""
```

To disable/reenable the block, simply remove/re-add the leading hash sign (`#`) in the first line.

This can even be used for a fast switch between two code blocks:

```
#"""
this_block_is_active_now()
"""
this_block_alternatively_gets_active_when_removing_the_hash_sign()
#"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to create a switch. This keeps all of your otherwise """ comment """ sections from turning each other on and off. It is also easy to disable and run as a code chunk and easy to find and delete for when you want to make the chunk a final version.

lightSwitch = "off"

if lightSwitch = "off":

```
 pass
```

else:

```
 `script`
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason I want this is for people using the very useful "Check" feature in the Mu editor/sdk.

I like commenting each line to the right of the code.  The problem is even a small comment there gets flagged as "Line too long (103 > 88 characters)"

Even in Arduino SDK I can create a macro level function that totally removes code, for example if one uncomments out the #define DEBUG line in the following code snippet.  Is Python capable of something similar to that? Whatever is in between 'DB('   and ')', whether within one line or many, gets totally removed before the compiler (or hopefully also interpreter) even sees it:

```
//#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
     #define DB(arg) { arg }
#else
     #define DB(arg) {   }
#endif
```